# Query DynamoDB secondary index by date range returns "Query key condition not supported"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

**CURRENTLY**

I am trying to retrieve a subset of data filtered by date range `transDate` (secondary index) from DynamoDB using Lambda.

Function:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var dynamodbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

let params = {
    "TableName": "sales",
    "IndexName": "transDate-index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#tdate BETWEEN :v_start AND :v_end",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#tdate": "transDate"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v_start": "2021-07-29T00:00:00",
        ":v_end": "2021-08-01T24:00:00"
    }
}

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   dynamodbClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(
           "Unable to query. Error:",
           JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
        );
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        resolve(data);
      }
  });
});
```

Secondary Index:

```
Name: transDate-index
Partition key:  transDate (String)
Sort key: -
Read capacity:  On-demand
Projected attributes: Include: total, pluGroup, plu, transDate
Size: 0 Bytes
Item count: 0
```

**ISSUE**

I receive the following error:

```
"message": "Query key condition not supported",
"code": "ValidationException"
```

**Notes**

I assume the Size and Item Count for the secondary index are both showing 0 because they haven't been populated yet (i.e. newly created index)

**QUESTION**

How can I get my query to work?

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't support what you're trying to achieve: if you don't have a specific partition key, the only way to access records is via a full table scan, which you definitely don't want.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee isn't `Partition key:  transDate (String)` a specific partition key? Do you know what HashKey & SortKey should use on the Table and or Secondary Index so that the query is successful?

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear, you need a specific partition key *value*. You can't ask DynamoDB for 'all records with a partition key between X and Y.' You can only ask for either all records or records with a specific partition key value.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee, thank you. I think I may have been mistaken / misled based on some stackoverflow posts I've read. I will use SCAN instead because I cannot think of a more efficient way of running the query. Although that being said, you would think that with QUERY if a SORT key is provided, DynamoDB could query a range on the sorted data to avoid scanning the entire database.

Comment: DynamoDB is a distributed database. Your records are spread out all over the place: the only guarantee is that all records with the same partition key are stored in the same place. There is no sorted view of the entire table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name implies, a partition key (aka a HASH key) is used to partition your data into multiple parts. It cannot be sorted or queried by range. To do that, you would need to make it a sort key (aka a RANGE key), and choose something else as a partition key (as a partition key is required while a sort key is optional).

Edit:
DynamoDB `Query` only supports querying on a single partition, thus a partition key is also required in the KeyConditionExpression:

```
"KeyConditionExpression": "partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval AND #tdate BETWEEN :v_start AND :v_end"
```

If you need to query your whole table, then in your secondary index, every record needs to have the same partition key value (i.e. there is only one partition).

Comment: I have made `transDate` a Sort Key, and also the Hash Key on a secondary Index. Using the same query as before, I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Wronski Sorry, did you make `transDate` the sort key in your secondary index?

Comment: Yes, when `transDate` is the sort key, error = "Query condition missed key schema element: uuid". Do you know what the HashKey & SortKey should be on the Table + Secondary Index so that the query is successful?

Comment: @Wronski See my update. I forgot that `KeyConditionExpression` also requires a partition key.